# Understanding step in Rotman´s proof of $|ST||S\cap T|=|S||T|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

So im not being able to understand a statement in the proof of the following theorem:

> Theorem: If $S,T$ are subgroups of a finite group $G$ then
>
> $$|ST||S\cap T|=|S||T|$$

So he starts by defining $\varphi:S \times T \to ST$ by $\varphi (s,t)=st$. He proceeds by stating that since $\varphi$ is a surjection, it suffices to show that if $x \in ST$ then $|\varphi^{-1}(x)|=|S\cap T|$. With no further explanation he demonstrates de later statement and concludes the demonstration. So Im having trouble in understanding why $\varphi$ being a surjection implies that it is enough to show that $|\varphi^{-1}(x)|=|S\cap T|$ to conclude the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a different point of view can help your understanding. The map $\varphi\colon S\times T\to ST$ defined by $\varphi(s,t)=st$ is surjective. Define an equivalence relation on $S\times T$ by declaring
$$
(s,t)\sim(s',t') \text{ if and only if }\varphi(s,t)=\varphi(s',t')
$$
(that is, $st=s't'$). Then $\varphi$ induces a bijection $S\times T/{\sim}\to ST$, so the number of equivalence classes is $|ST|$.

If we prove that all equivalence classes with respect to $\sim$ have the same number of elements $k$, we'll know that $|ST|=|S\times T|/k$, because $S\times T$ is partitioned in classes with the same number of elements $k$.

Now the equivalence class of $(s,t)$ is precisely $\varphi^{-1}(st)$. When we have proved that, for each $x\in ST$ we have $|\varphi^{-1}(x)|=|S\cap T|$ we have precisely determined we're in the hoped for situation and that $k=|S\cap T|$.

The idea is the same as the common proof of Lagrange's theorem: a subgroup $H$ of $G$ defines an equivalence relation $x\sim y$ if and only if $x^{-1}y\in H$. The equivalence classes have the same cardinality as $H$, so $|G|$ is $|H|$ times the number of equivalence classes. In the present case the number of equivalence classes is $|ST|$ and their common cardinality is $|S\cap T|$.

---

The proof can be done as follows: let $x\in ST$. Fix $(s_0,t_0)$ such that $x=s_0t_0$; for $(s,t)\in\varphi^{-1}(x)$, consider that $st=s_0t_0$, so $s_0^{-1}s=t_0t^{-1}\in S\cap T$; then define
$$
f\colon \varphi^{-1}(x)\to S\cap T
$$
by $f(s,t)=s_0^{-1}s=t_0t^{-1}$ and prove it is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

The author simply uses the *shepherd's principle*:

*Shepherd's principle (1st version)*

Let $\mathcal P$ be a partition of a finite set $E$, and suppose each $X\in\mathcal P$ has the same cardinality $n$. Then $\;\lvert E\rvert=n\lvert\mathcal P\rvert$.

*Shepherd's principle (2nd version)*

Let $f\colon E\longrightarrow F$ a surjective map between finite sets. If each $f^{-1}(x)$ $\;(x\in E)$ has the same cardinality $n$, then  $\;\lvert E\rvert=n\lvert F\rvert$.

Comment: Which is? It´s not even in Wikipedia..

Comment: It's a metaphoric name. It says that, to count  sheep in his flock, a shepherd counts legs and divides the result by four.

Comment: Mhm.. and how does the shepard's principle applies to this precise situation?

Comment: Each inverse image by φ has the same number of elements, just as, in the mapping from the set of legs onto the set of sheep, each ‘inverse image of a sheep’ has 4 elements. It has nothing to do with group theory, only with combinatorics.

Comment: Yes. I see. Still don't understand the logic behind this statement and the product formula.

Comment: You have a surjection from S×T onto ST. |S×T| = |S| |T| and each inverse image has cardinality  |S$\cap$T|, isn't it clear these data yield the result?

Comment: No! That is precisely what Im asking in this question!

Comment: |S×T| is equal to the sum of the number of elements in each subset member of  the partition. These subsets all have |S$\cap$T| elements, so you can factor this number. The other factor is the number of subsets in the partition, which is the number of elements in ST, by definition.